# How can I profile a Java application running on my LAN?

Tags: java, jmx, lan, jvisualvm

I am trying to profile a Java application running on my LAN from JVisualVM.

However, when I start my program with arguments like:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

I am unable to connect through JVisualVM, with JMX or jstatd.

9000 is forwarded, of course, and the server uses Ubuntu.

Comment: What is the error? Is there a firewall between VisualVM and the Java application?

Comment: The port 9000 has been forwarded on the server, and there is no firewall between my machine and the server. The only error is that JVisualVM just can't connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, JMX will open another random port besides the one specified with `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port`. Since Java 7u25, you can set this port to a fixed value:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1234
```

You may set it to the same port as `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21552812/3790806) for details.

If you are still having problems with the connection, try debugging it with JConsole. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455831/debugging-jconsole-connection-failed) for details.

Comment: It's still not connecting. Do I need to have jstatd running on the host as well? I'm not entirely sure my jstatd script is working, since I can't connect with jstatd or JMX on JVisualVM.

Comment: No, you don't need jstatd if you are using JMX. Try debugging the JMX connection with JConsole: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7444718/3790806

Comment: The problem was the lack of `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=[LAN IP]`, thank you!